# Magento: A question about collection LIMIT by the way "Zend Db limit"

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, model

There are several ways to limit collection for magento you could find here [Magento: Set LIMIT on collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322333/magento-set-limit-on-collection).
I tried the best answer, both ways work well.

But when I am trying, I met a question is about the "Zend Db limit" way.
When I use the "Zend Db limit" way like below, it works well.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('...')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

But if I use the way like follows, it doesn't work.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('...')->getCollection()->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

I do not understand the difference between the two wordings. Why one is valid and the other is invalid. Maybe this is a stupid question, but I've been stuck here for a long time, I want to know the reason.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only difference i see is which method return what to calling
>   object

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('...')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

above code works because you have assigned model collection object to $collection varibale in first line.

in second line you set limit on select object of collection.

$collection variable still hold model collection object.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('...')->getCollection()->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

in above code you have called function using "**method chaining**" method

which will return select object from collection and not original model collection object

To simply check `var_dump(get_class($collection));` for both case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Select object is part of Collection object,  `$collection->getSelect()->limit(20);` set the Select object'property ["limitcount"] in the Collection object, do i understand right?

Comment: @ArthurSereno yes.You are correct